# tooltip's aren't "centered" despite direction: center being set

Tags: leaflet

I'm creating labels for polygons with the following code:

```
L.marker(polygon.getBounds().getCenter())
    .bindTooltip('County Name', {permanent: true, direction: 'center'})
    .addTo(mymap);
```

However, the result isn't exactly what I'd call centered. Like the majority of the tooltip is on the right side of the marker whereas I'd expect the marker to be smack dab in the middle of the tooltip.

Any ideas as to what I can do to improve the situation?

If I can get this working I'll hide the marker by doing `{opacity: 0}` but if I do that now it'll look off center without a frame of reference.

[image]

Comment: Have you already read [Finding the center of Leaflet polygon?](https://resultfor.dev/362607-finding-the-center-of-leaflet-polygon). Just as an idea for a test - create a separate point layer with the desired positions in addition.

Comment: @help-info.de - `polygon.getBounds().getCenter()` is finding the center point. That's where the _marker_ is being placed. That's not my issue. My issue is that the _tooltip_ does not appear to be centered around the marker, in spite of `direction: 'center'` being set.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add labels to the polygon you can use instead customised `Tooltip`.

In your Javascript code :

```js
let custom_popup = L.popup()
        .setLatLng(polygon.getBounds().getCenter())
        .setContent('County name')
        .addTo(map);
```

[image: Tooltip without customsation]

Then you can customise to make it look like a `Marker` using CSS :

```css
.leaflet-popup-close-button // we remove the X to close the popup
{ 
    display: none;
}

.leaflet-popup-tip          // We remove the arrow pointing at the coordinates
{
    display: none;
}

.leaflet-popup-content      // We center the text inside the Tooltip
{
    text-align: center;
}
```

Here's the result :

[image: Tooltip after customisation]